# Configure Flymake for proselint

Tags: flymake

[proselint](http://proselint.com/) is a prose linter which returns error/warning messages like this:

```
2020-09-09-still-processing.md:18:14: typography.symbols.curly_quotes Use curly quotes “”, not straight quotes "".
```

I know there is a proselint checker in Flycheck, but I am trying to configure Flymake. For this task, I am using [flymake-easy](https://github.com/purcell/flymake-easy) like this:

```lisp
(defconst flymake-proselint-err-line-patterns
  '(("^\\(.*\.md\\):\\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\): \\(.*\\)$" 1 2 3 4)))

(defvar flymake-proselint-executable "proselint"
  "The proselint executable to use for syntax checking.")

(defun flymake-proselint-command (filename)
  "Construct a command that flymake can use to check Markdown in FILENAME."
  (list flymake-proselint-executable filename))

(defun flymake-proselint-load ()
  "Configure flymake mode to check the current buffer's ruby syntax."
  (interactive)
  (flymake-easy-load 'flymake-proselint-command
                     flymake-proselint-err-line-patterns
                     'tempdir
                     "md"))

(defun flymake-proselint-maybe-load ()
  "Call `flymake-proselint-load' if this file appears to be Markdown."
  (interactive)
  (if (and buffer-file-name
           (string= "md" (file-name-extension buffer-file-name)))
      (flymake-proselint-load)))
```

I added `flymake-proselint-maybe-load` to `markdown-mode-hook` but `flymake-show-diagnostics-buffer` shows an empty buffer instead of the above-mentioned message from `proselint`.

My guess is I am setting `flymake-proselint-err-line-patterns`, but I am not sure if this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took another approach, using [flymake-quickdef](https://github.com/karlotness/flymake-quickdef), so as to leverage `flymake-diagnostic-functions`:

```lisp
(require 'flymake-quickdef)
(flymake-quickdef-backend
  flymake-proselint-backend
  :pre-let ((proselint-exec (executable-find "proselint")))
  :pre-check (unless proselint-exec (error "proselint not found on PATH"))
  :write-type 'pipe
  :proc-form (list proselint-exec "-")
  :search-regexp "^.+:\\([[:digit:]]+\\):\\([[:digit:]]+\\): \\(.+\\)$"
  :prep-diagnostic
  (let* ((lnum (string-to-number (match-string 1)))
         (lcol (string-to-number (match-string 2)))
         (msg (match-string 3))
         (pos (flymake-diag-region fmqd-source lnum lcol))
         (beg (car pos))
         (end (cdr pos)))
    (list fmqd-source beg end :warning msg)))

(defun flymake-proselint-setup ()
  "Enable flymake backend."
  (add-hook 'flymake-diagnostic-functions #'flymake-proselint-backend nil t))
```

Then it's just a matter of adding `flymake-proselint-setup` to `markdown-mode-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook #'flymake-proselint-setup)
```

Comment: By the way, I packaged this code and make it available to anyone interested: https://github.com/manuel-uberti/flymake-proselint

Comment: For the record, the repository has been moved on SourceHut: https://git.sr.ht/~manuel-uberti/flymake-proselint